# Calculate this infinite sum: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+3}{2^n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$s= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+3}{(2^n)(n+1)(n+2)}$$
Any method to calculate this type of infinite sums?

Comment: It is a duplicate of a recent question. Telescoping is the trick.

Comment: Can u send me the link of the recent question?

Comment: I cannot find it now, but it simply relies on the identity: $$\frac{2^{-(n+1)}}{(n+1)}-\frac{2^{-(n+2)}}{n+2}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{(n+3)}{2^n(n+1)(n+2)}.$$

Comment: generatingfunctionology... Start with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = 1/(1-x)$, then [doing derivatives, integrals, multiplying by powers of $x$] derive the formula for $\sum x^n (n+2)/((n+1)(n+2))$.  Then take $x=1/2$.  This method is applicable even if the series does not fortuitously telescope.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$$\text{let }\frac{n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac A{n+1}+\frac B{n+2}$$

$$n+3=n(A+B)+2A+B\implies A+B=1,2A+B=3\implies A=2, B=-1$$

$$\implies\frac{n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac 2{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}$$

$$\implies\frac{n+3}{2^n(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{(1/2)^{n-1}}{n+1}-\frac{(1/2)^n}{n+2}$$

If $T_m=\dfrac{(1/2)^{m-1}}{m+1},$

$$\frac{n+3}{2^n(n+1)(n+2)}=T(n)-T(n+1)$$ which is clearly [Telescoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)